# helpers and session in CI while using database error

Tags: php, codeigniter

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /srv/disk5/1241421/www/ebazzar.co.nf/application/models/product_model.php:2)
>
> Filename: libraries/Session.php
>
> Line Number: 672

...

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /srv/disk5/1241421/www/ebazzar.co.nf/application/models/product_model.php:2)
>
> Filename: helpers/url_helper.php
>
> Line Number: 542

How can I solve this error?
It appears when add some content in the database

function goes like this:

```
public function signup() {
    if ($this->authex->logged_in()) {
        redirect('welcome');
    }
    //$data['page'] = $this->uri->segment(2);
    $data['fproducts'] = $this->pm->get_fproducts();
    $data['countries'] = $this->pm->get_countries();
    if ($this->input->post('submit_signup')) {
        if ($this->_form_validate() == FALSE) {
            $this->load->view('header', $data);
            $this->load->view('sidebar');
            $this->load->view('signup');
            $this->load->view('footer');
        } else {
            $signup_id = $this->pm->add_user();
            if ($signup_id) {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message', array('title' => 'Signup Result', 'content' => 'You have been successfully registered', 'type' => 'message'));

                redirect("welcome/home");
            }
        }
    } else {
        $this->load->view('header', $data);
        $this->load->view('sidebar');
        $this->load->view('signup');
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems there is some output before the session is started, you can check what those extra output is. Probably an error, notice or something you added.

Comment: but it absolutely works well in localhost and i guess i shouldn't mess with codeigniter framework and its session library

Comment: pls post the fn that produce error

Comment: ebazzar.co.nf and these errors appears in signup.. but the data are inserted in database even with the errors

Comment: Try to disable all error. I mean that change to production mode!

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that your `redirect` function is using the PHP `header` function, the problem is this:

The `header` function is supposed to be called **before** any output otherwise it will not work. You are obviously outputting something else before calling that function.

Rearrange your code so that the output is printed at the end of the file, or use the `ob_*` functions family to control the output buffer.

Notice that to fix the problem the error is also telling you where the invalid output, before the `header` call, is started:

> output started at /srv/disk5/1241421/www/ebazzar.co.nf/application/models/product_model.php:2

Comment: thanks Jeffrey. i found it . there was an empty new line after and before ( <?php ) on line number 2. thanks for your help.